# How to add additional column to the dynamodb using aws cli?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli, aws-serverless

I need to add few more columns to my dynamodb. As per the documentation, I tried something, but it's not working as expected:

```
aws dynamodb update-table --table-name product-v1 --AttributeDefinitions AttributeName=Prize,AttributeType=S
```

It throws an error:

> Unknown option error

Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

AttributeDefinition is used to define the key schema for the table and indexes, not columns. since  DynamoDB is a NoSQL table design you don't really have to define the columns

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.html